# Can't get migrations to work: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm taking a course in MVC that was recorded in 2016, so maybe that has to do with this error. It says to open NuGet console and type in "Enable-Migrations" in order to enable Entity Framework. But when I type that I get all sorts of error messages and yes I double-checked to make sure I'm doing everything the instructor is. I tried different versions of EF in Nuget Package Manager and the error messages change but still happen.

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
Enable-Migrations : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-Migrations
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Enable-Migrations], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Enable-Migrations
```

First off, why is this even necessary? From what I've seen of EF and LINQ so far I'd rather code in machine language, but in courses I took before that used EF we never had to do "Migrations" before so I'd like to solve this error message but I don't even see the point of it. I thought I read somewhere that Microsoft in its infinite wisdom has changed the way we do migrations but can't find any updated documentation.

Comment: please check your directory. you need to cd to your project directory for the command to work

Comment: With what version of EF are you getting this error?

Comment: duplicate see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58093448/enable-migrations-cannot-bind-argument-to-parameter-path/58138106#58138106

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type following command in package manager console.

```
dir
```

or

```
pwd
```

pwd show you the path of current directory. 
dir list down all folders of current directory. if package manager console is not set to project directory, run

```
cd "YouProjectDirectory"
```

and run

```
Enable-Migrations
```

If you install required packages in this case entitty framework core packages, it will run successfully.